# Создать массив в функции, используя параметр

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

```
void countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int* output[] = new int[n] ; // output array 
    int i, count[10] = { 0 };
```

В данном примере при попытке создания массива `output`, возникает ошибка под `new`: «*для агрегатного объекта требуется инициализация...*». Пробовал делать просто `int output [n];`, но VS не позволяет так сделать (возможно, отсутствует поддержка VLA).

Когда делаю такое на C, проблема та же, только после компиляции «ругается» на `malloc`. Вопрос: как создать массив в функции, используя для его размера параметр функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `new` выделит для массива память и вернет **указатель** на этот выделенный для вас участок памяти. Вы же пытаетесь присвоить указатель (`int *`) массиву (`int []`). Решение — сделать переменную `output` указателем:

```
int *output = new int[n];
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!